# Using "struct xxx<>::val" in template metaprogramming caused error

Tags: c++, templates, struct, template-meta-programming

I wrote a basic C++ template metaprogramming demo using enum in struct to calculate fibonacci and it does not compile on either GCC 4.9 or MSVC 14.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int N> 
struct fib {
    enum {val = fib<N-1>::val + fib<N-2>::val};
};

template <>
struct fib<1> {
    enum {val = 1};
};

template<>
struct fib<2> {
    enum {val =2};
};


int main() {
    // error: 'val' in 'struct fib<4>' does not name a type
    struct fib<4>::val;

    // expected ';' before 'struct
    // expected primary-expression before '<<' token 
    cout << struct fib<40>::val; 

    cout << fib<40>::val; // works

    return 0;
}
```

I know this is the "C way" of declaring a struct instance and that in C++ it is recommended to ditch "struct" keyword and just declare it as declaring a class instance. But since struct is supported and the syntax of `struct structName varName;` does work in normal circumstances, I am curious of what went wrong here or if such a way of declaration is potentially conflict with template parsing done by the compiler. Thanks!

Comment: Well, both lines are not declarations. What would they declare anyway?

Answer (score 5):

`val` is a value, not a type. You can't prefix it with `struct` just like you can't say `struct 1`. Also, yes, drop the prolific `struct` usage because it's fallen out of style in C++.

Comment: Thanks. I personally never add the excessive "struct", and this code is just to experiment what will happen if I do that. Initially I thought ```struct fib<4>``` should be effectively the same as ```fib<4>``` since the former is just trying to be C-compatible. I guess what you are trying to say is that this form will trigger ambiguity when used with template so it simply does not work?

Comment: `struct fib<4>` is the same as `fib<4>`. But `fib<4>` is very different from `fib<4>::val`.

Comment: Thanks. I know fib<4>::val is enum type accessed through the template struct fib. However I put struct in front hoping to achieve the effect of (struct fib<4>)::val where the parenthesis is just what I had in my mind that compiler would recognize ```struct fib<4>``` as ```fib<4>``` and proceed with ```fib<4>::val```. I guess it does not work that way but why?